# Why is JVM -Xms option not simply 0?

Tags: java, performance, heap-memory

Why does the JVM have an `-Xms` option? Why do we care about a minimum heap size? Why not just 0? It's super easy to allocate RAM, so I don't see the point of forcing a minimum heap size.

In my searching, I see that it's customary to set `-Xms` (minimum heap size) and `-Xmx` (maximum heap size) to the same value.

I am having a hard time finding a clear and rational basis for this custom or why `-Xms` even exists. Rather, I find a lot of [communal reinforcement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communal_reinforcement). On occasion, I see it justified by a flaky theory, such that the JVM is unusually slow at allocating additional RAM as it grows the heap size.

While this came up as I was optimizing Solr, it seems that fussing with the heap size is a common consideration with JVMs.

As a curious data point, you'll see two memory-usage dips here:
[image: Memory changes when I change JVMheap settings.]

- Before dip 1: `-Xms14g -Xmx14g`
- Between dip 1 and 2: `-Xms0g -Xmx14g`
- After dip 2: `-Xmx14g`

After dip 2, Solr reported to me that it was only using a couple hundred MBs of heap space even though the JVM gobbled up many GBs of RAM.

In case it matters, I am on the current release of OpenJDK.

To summarize, is there a rational and fact-based basis for:

- Setting `-Xms` to something other than 0.
- The custom of setting `-Xms` and `-Xmx` to the same value.
- Why `-Xms` even exists.

I think the fact-based basis will help with a more informed basis for managing heap-size options.

Answer (score 0):

You have three questions.

**First question:**

> *Is there a rational and fact-based basis for setting `-Xms` to something other than 0?*

[Looking as far back as version 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), we can see (among other things) the following for `-Xms`:

> *Sets the minimum and the initial size (in bytes) of the heap.*

So, setting `-Xms` to 0 would mean setting the heap to 0. I'm not sure what your expectation would be, but.. the JVM needs at least some amount of heap to do things (like run a garbage collector).

**Second question:**

> *Is there a rational and fact-based basis for the custom of setting `-Xms` and `-Xmx` to the same value?*

Yes, if you expect to use a certain amount of memory over time, but not necessarily right away. You could allocate the full amount of memory up front so that any allocation costs are out of the way.

For example, consider an app that launches needing less than 1GB of memory, but over time it grows (normally, correctly) to 4GB. You could run that app with `-Xms1g -Xmx4g` – so, start with 1GB and do periodic allocations over time to reach 4GB. Or you could run with `-Xms4g -Xmx4g` – tell the JVM to allocate 4GB now, even if it's not going to be used right away.

Allocating memory from an underlying operating system has a cost, and might be expensive enough that you'd like to do that early in the application life, instead of some later point where that cost might be more impactful.

**Third question:**

> *Is there a rational and fact-based basis for why `-Xms` even exists?*

Yes, it allows tuning JVM behavior. Some applications don't need to do this, but others do. It's useful to be able to set values for lower, upper, or both (lower and upper together). Way beyond this, there's a whole world of garbage collector tuning, too.

A little more detail on how `-Xms` is used (below) could give you some initial garbage collection topics to read about (old generation, young generation):

> *If you do not set this option, then the initial size will be set as the sum of the sizes allocated for the old generation and the young generation.*

Comment: "setting -Xms to 0 would mean setting the heap to 0." <-- I am not clear on this statement. 0 is simply a lower bound. The `-Xmx` setting would be more like what you're referring to.

Comment: "any allocation costs" <-- Memory allocation costs are super low for reasonably designed software. What problem does this really solve?

Comment: Setting `-Xms` and `-Xmx` to the same value has a cost though: it disables some of the GC ergonomics.

Comment: @ArenCambre If you would be able to set `-Xms` to zero, that would seriously increase the start up time for your application: each time memory must be increased, Java will first do a full GC. Having to do a lot of full GCs before reaching a steady-state in memory consumption can be very costly (CPU and time).

Comment: re: allocation costs - Growing memory beyond what the JVM has already allocated involves interacting with the operating system (which manages all memory for the entire system). If that interaction is slow enough, and/or performance demands of your app are high enough, that could become a cost you don't want to incur at unpredictable times. As with any performance tuning, it's a game of trade-offs and compromises. I like that we have a number of mechanisms to tune the JVM, but there's no "one way". It's about having options.

Comment: Thanks. From these comments, I sense a belief pervades the Java world that Java's memory-allocation mechanism is inefficient or unsophisticated. That is a neutral statement; I am not sure if it simply means Java delegates more of those matters to the application than what is customary elsewhere, or if there is some correctable problem with Java's design. Outside of Java, I can't recall ever having to "tune" heap allocations. It "just works".

Comment: "If you would be able to set -Xms to zero, that would seriously increase the start up time for your application" <-- @MarkRotteveel can you share any real-world evidence to back up this belief?

Comment: @ArenCambre You can try with any Java application that requires a significant amount of memory immediately after start up, compare the differences in start up times with a very low -Xms and a very high -Xms.

Comment: @kaan I think your argument hinges on this statement: "If that interaction [with the OS to allocate more memory] is slow enough" Can you share evidence that this interaction is meaningfully slow? I am not sure that is true, and I am having a hard time understanding how an occasional use of this is a real problem. Of course, a poorly designed app might use this too much and slow things down, but any app that uses some resource too much is simply a poorly designed app, and I am not sure why we'd mitigate poorly designed apps with fussy JVM-level configuration.

Comment: "each time memory must be increased, Java will first do a full GC" <-- I'm lost on that. GC is what you do to _reduce_ memory needs. You're saying a GC has to be done before we _increase_ memory allocation, which should defer the need for a GC?

Comment: "You can try with any Java application that requires a significant amount of memory immediately after start up" I did that already. Look at the Task Manager screenshot above. Solr gobbled up many GBs of RAM upon start quite quickly regardless of `-Xms` setting. Either way, it was so fast that I would not wish to tune `-Xms` at all.

Comment: @ArenCambre I'm not thinking of "poor app design" as a cause for slowness, but more like demands for always fast response (millisecond-level SLA where a GC pause of 200ms would violate your application SLA) or high-volume input (this reflects my own experience, working with 10's of thousands of data inputs per second). I'd suggest reading about GC pauses, how long they take, how to diagnose, how to tune. I gather this is a world you maybe haven't encountered yet, but it's why these tuning options exist.

Comment: I appreciate the need for high-response, mission-critical scenarios. That is not what I associate overwhelming use of Java with, however. Java is mainly for 1. delay-tolerating enterprise software or 2. software made with it because "that's the tool I know".  That said, I reviewed https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/6n5srlhqf/index.html and found this: "When the heap grows or shrinks, the JVM must recalculate the old and new generation sizes..." How impactful is that operation? Is does the JVM allocate new memory in an optimal way, or is it simply dumb and reactive to micro changes?

Comment: @ArenCambre you have it backwards. The JVM doesn’t perform a GC “before increasing memory” intentionally, because the JVM doesn’t know beforehand whether it will increase the memory. The chain of events is 1) detect that the currently allocated memory is not enough 2) try to reduce the memory consumption via GC 3) find that the GC did not reclaim enough memory 4) expand the heap memory. The first two steps are the ordinary GC approach happening all the time, usually without increasing memory. But if we know beforehand that x GB are needed, we can skip the JVM’s work to find that out.

Comment: Thank you. That makes more sense. Is this order set by a deterministic process, so that it always happens that way? Also, while the details are fuzzy to me, it sounds like GC is also triggered by heuristics and that there is not a situation where GC would _never_ be triggered over the life of a long-lived app. Therefore, if the pre-heap-expansion GC is a portion of what would have at some point been a some portion of a _natural_ GC cycle, then over the life of the app, no harm no foul, and we're back to these settings being meaningless fuss.

Comment: The decision to expand or shrink the heap is made right after a GC, because that’s the point of time when the exact memory consumption is known. In principle, the heap will expand as necessary, so pre-sizing the heap usually only saves a few GC cycles at startup. But in some cases, the automatic expansion may end up with a smaller heap and performing more cycles than with forced larger heap. Note that you won’t see this difference in the Task Manager, as it will only show actually used memory, so memory preallocated with `-Xms` won’t show up before the application actually writes data into it.